# How to cancel installation of my module if requirements are not met

Tags: 7, installation

My module depends on a PHP library (sites/all/libraries/xyz/xyz-library.php). I want drupal to continue with installation only if library requirements of my module are met.

I want something of this kind, in my `mymodule.install`:

```
function mymodule_install() {
  if( library_exists() )   return; //continue with installation
  else{
    drupal_set_message(t('Installation failed. Please put xyz-library.php in sites/all/libraries/xyz folder.'), 'error');
    return FALSE; // installation failed
  }
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can do this in `hook_requirements`, from the [documentation](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7):

> During the 'install' phase, modules can for example assert that
>   library or server versions are available or sufficient. Note that the
>   installation of a module can happen during installation of Drupal
>   itself (by install.php) with an installation profile or later by hand.
>   As a consequence, install-time requirements must be checked without
>   access to the full Drupal API, because it is not available during
>   install.php. For localization you should for example use $t = get_t()
>   to retrieve the appropriate localization function name (t() or st()).
>   If a requirement has a severity of REQUIREMENT_ERROR, install.php will
>   abort or at least the module will not install. Other severity levels
>   have no effect on the installation. Module dependencies do not belong
>   to these installation requirements, but should be defined in the
>   module's .info file.

After your check, you return array (see docs again) with `REQUIREMENT_ERROR`.

```
function example_requirements($phase) {
  $requirements = array();
  // Ensure translations do not break at install time
  $t = get_t();

  $requirements['example'] = array(
    'title' => $t('Example Library'),
  );

  $libraries = libraries_get_libraries();
  if (isset($libraries['example'])) {
    $requirements['example']['value'] = $t('Installed');
    $requirements['example']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_OK;
  }
  else {
    $requirements['example']['value'] = $t('Not Installed');
    $requirements['example']['severity'] = REQUIREMENT_ERROR;
    $requirements['example']['description'] = $t('Please install the example library %url.', array('%url' => 'http://example.com'));
  }

  return $requirements;
}
```

You can check this code example [here](http://engineeredweb.com/blog/10/5/3-tips-using-external-libraries-drupal/).

Answer (score 4):

Sounds like you're looking for [hook_requirements()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_requirements/7), which will abort the installation if the requirements are not met.

So if your module was named `mymodule`, you'd create a function called `mymodule_requirements()` inside the file `mymodule.install`.